# Reporting ignored tests, and getting live reports in JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Using the JUnit assumeTrue, you can skip a test, but is there any way to tell JUnit that the test has been skipped?  It seems to just report that the test has passed....

Also, is there any way to detect during the @After method, if any tests have failed?

E.g.

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
  //.... How many tests passed and how many failed?
}
```

I know this information is reported at the *end* of all the tests, but I would like to be able to access it in the @After function.

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to point 2... its a userbility improvement to log current statistics as the test is running.  This is useful if the test suite takes 10+ minutes to run... its nice to know if there was a failure early on.

Comment: If your tests are that slow you must make them faster. That sounds more like integration tests and not Unit tests...

Comment: Its a selenium frontend with a JUnit back end... its not actually 'unit testing' per say, but selenium uses JUnit to report usability test failures.

Comment: For the first part couldn't you use the @Ignore tag?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - Yes, but I do not believe there is a way to make this conditional?

Comment: Have a look at the experimental 'Max' feature in Junit 4.7 (see release nodes: https://3licenses.svn.codeplex.com/svn/thirdparty/junit/junit-4.7/README.html) -- may it helps you to run the relevant tests earlyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, is there any way to detect during the @After method, if any tests have failed?

You can implement your own Test Runner:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
```

@See: org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

Or you can have a look at TestDecorators (in JUnit 4.7) junit.extensions.TestDecorator. That sounds like the thing you need, but I have no expirance with.